# FB - Application doesn't have permission for this action (Error 10)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

In the Facebook developer page of my iPhone app, I see *auth.extendssoaccesstoken*   error under **Insights->Developer->Activity & Errors**. I don't understand what is causing this and how to fix this.

Also please help me with how to check whether this issue has resolved from client side.

I have integrated Facebook SDK 3.1 in my iPhone app.

Comment: I am getting the same error can anyone help